# FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.then; then isn't defined

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

So i want to implement role based authentication to my app in flutter. Only users with the permissions should get to this site. Im getting the error:

> The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'User'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'then'.

I've tried to solve it for 2 hours now, but every tutorial is outdated or not for my usecase.

Full code of Authentication Handler:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:learnon/screens/lehrerstartpage.dart';


import '../screens/startscreen.dart';
import '../screens/auth_screen.dart';

class AutoLoginHandler extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      //Streambuilder looks if data is avaliable
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
          return MainPage(); //when data here goto Startscreen
        }
        return LoginScreen(); //when no data is here goto Login
      },
    );
  }

final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  authorizeAccess(BuildContext context) {
    
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.then((user) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('/users')
          .where('uid', isEqualTo: user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((results) {
   if (results.size > 0) {
          if (results.docs[0].data()['role'] == 'admin') 
         {
            Navigator.of(context).push(new 
   MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => new 
   LehrerMainPage()));
          }
   }
});
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Try getting the user by doing `FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();`

Comment: The [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/) is not out of date.  Start there.  The error message is telling you that the currentUser property is a User object and does not have a method called `then`.